# The best way of adding countdown label with timer in UICollectionViewCell which works fine even after cell is being reused

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, timer, uicollectionviewcell

I have a list of items which are presenting to the user in  `UICollectionView`. These items have a countdown label to show the remaining time that the item is available.
I used a `Timer` in `UICollectionViewCell` to show the remaining time like:

```
OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        var remaingTimeInterval = self.calculateRemainigTime(remainingTime: remainingTime)
        if remaingTimeInterval > 0 {
            self.timerLabel.isHidden = false
            self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (_) in
                let hours = Int(remaingTimeInterval) / 3600
                let minutes = Int(remaingTimeInterval) / 60 % 60
                let seconds = Int(remaingTimeInterval) % 60
                self?.timerLabel?.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
                remaingTimeInterval -= 1
            })
        } else {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            self.timerLabel.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

and that's how I calculate the remaining time based on the given Date:

```
//Calculating remaining time based on the item endDate and currentDAte
    func calculateRemainigTime(remainingTime: String) -> Int {
        let prizeRemainingTime = Helper.stringToDate(remainingTime)
        let prizeRemainingTimeInterval = Int(prizeRemainingTime.timeIntervalSince1970)
        let currentTimeInterval = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
        return prizeRemainingTimeInterval - currentTimeInterval
    }
```

Everything works fine till the cell is being reused, after that the countdown numbers are not correct anymore.

Is this a correct way to show the countdown in UICollectionViewCell or there is a better solution.

Can anyone help me to find a way through this?

Comment: A better solution is to run the timer in the data model rather than in the view.

Comment: what do you mean? adding a property in data model to save the remaining time? so how to update it every second?

Comment: For example you could run the timer in the model and pass the action or callback in `cellForRow` to the cell

Comment: I don't think that works, because ````cellForRow```` is call only when cell is going to be reused, but I have to show the count down every second.

Comment: To make it clearer: You use the block based API of `Timer` and pass the block  in `cellForRow` to the cell. As long as the cell is visible when the timer fires it calls the block which updates the UI.

Comment: oh, now i get your point, let me try it and I will update you by the result.

Comment: @vadian , thanks that's the best answer, please post it as answer so I can be able to accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. I wrote an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Move the timer logic to the data model.
- Instead of target/action use the block-based API of `Timer`.
- In `cellForRow` pass the timer callback block to the cell.
- When the timer fires the code in the callback block can update the UI in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Coding from accepted answer guideline, hope you like it.

MyViewController

```
protocol MyViewControllerDelegate : class {
    func updateTimer(_ timeString: String)
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var timerDetegate: MyViewControllerDelegate?

    var timer = Timer()
    var time = 0

    fun ViewDidLoad() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
            self.time += 1
            self.timerDetegate?.updateTimer("time \(self.time)")
        })
    }

    ...

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViewdequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MeCell")
        vc.timerDetegate = cell
        return cell
    }

    ...

}
```

MyTableViewCell

```
class MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell, MyViewControllerDelegate {

    ...

    func updateTimer(_ timeString: String) {
        lblTimeLeft.text = timeString
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented this simpler way (without caring about the performance/latency)

in ..cellForItemAt.. method, I call

```
cell.localEndTime = yourEndTimeInterval
cell.startTimerProgress()
```

In collection view cell, I added a method which starts the progress:

```
    var localEndTime: TimeInterval = 0 //set value from model
    var timer:Timer?
    func timerIsRunning(timer: Timer){
        let diff = localEndTime  - Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        if diff  > 0 {
            self.showProgress()
            return
        }
        self.stopProgress()


    }
    func showProgress(){
        let endDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: localEndTime)
        let nowDate = Date()
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(Set([.day, .hour, .minute, .second]), from: nowDate, to: endDate)
        self?.timerLabel?.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", components.hour!, components.minute!, components.second!)

    }

    func stopProgress(){
         self?.timerLabel?.text = String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", 0, 0, 0)
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }

    func startTimerProgress() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.timerIsRunning(timer:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.timer?.fire()
    }
```