# Set timer for table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

i want to set timer for each table view cell. The goal is to delete a cell from the list once the time is zeroed. there is my code for customize timer. time string in cell not change.

```
private func CreateModel() {

    let m1 = ModelObject(bTime: "12:13:10", eTime: "12:20:10", cTime: "12:18:10", minus: "0")
    let m2 = ModelObject(bTime: "12:15:10", eTime: "12:25:10", cTime: "12:10:10", minus: "0")
    let m3 = ModelObject(bTime: "12:18:10", eTime: "12:30:10", cTime: "12:10:10", minus: "0")
    let m4 = ModelObject(bTime: "12:20:10", eTime: "12:35:10", cTime: "12:10:10", minus: "0")

    models.append(m1)
    models.append(m2)
    models.append(m3)
    models.append(m4)

  }
  func startTimer() {

    listUpdateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(reloadTable), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


  }

  @objc func reloadTable() {

    tableView.reloadData()
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimerTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TimerTableViewCell

    cell.delegate = self

    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone

    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    let currentDate = models[indexPath.row].currentTime ?? ""
    let maxDate = models[indexPath.row].endTime ?? ""

    let cDate = formatter.date(from: currentDate)! as NSDate
    let mDate = formatter.date(from: maxDate)! as NSDate

    if mDate.isGreaterThanDate(dateToCompare: cDate) {

      let minus : TimeInterval = mDate.timeIntervalSince(cDate as Date)
      print(minus)
      var m = models[indexPath.row].minus
      m = String(minus)

      cell.timeLabel.text = m

    }
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return models.count
  }
extension ViewController : TimerTableViewCellDelegate {

  func setCellTime(cell: TimerTableViewCell) {

    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {

      models[indexPath.row].minus = cell.myTime
    }
  }
}


protocol TimerTableViewCellDelegate {

  func setCellTime(cell:TimerTableViewCell)
}
class TimerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
  var delegate : TimerTableViewCellDelegate?
  var timer = Timer()
  var myTime = "0"

  override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    updateRow()

  }

  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
  }

  func updateRow(){
    print("**************")
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.decreaseTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

  @objc func decreaseTimer(){


    if let delegate = self.delegate {
      var time = Double(timeLabel.text!)!
      if time > 0 {

        time -= 1
      }
      self.myTime = String(time)

      delegate.setCellTime(cell: self)

    }
  }


}
```

i'm using protocol delegate for update cell data, in my case after each  table view reload calling cell timer should begin but this is not working.

Comment: **Never** run timers in the view (cell). Cells can be deallocated immediately. Run it in the model (the items in the data source array)

Comment: create model with timer??

Comment: Yes. that's what I mean

Comment: there is a discussion related to your problem in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46871799/1724845)

Comment: i'm using @vadian solution, this work fine. I will also try this. thanks